# Read file to std::string efficiently with windows line endings

Tags: c++, windows

One of the more efficient ways to read a file into a string in C++ is as follows:

```cpp
fstream file(filePath);
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
string fileContents;
fileContents.resize(file.tellg());
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
file.read(&fileContents[0], fileContents.size());
```

If this is on Windows though and the file has Windows style \r\n line endings, then the size of the string will end up larger than its contents due to the fact that tellg() reports the size of the file in bytes, whereas file.read() will translate \r\n into \n resulting in a smaller string than the size of the file.

I can think of several ways of dealing with this, but none of them is efficient nor elegant.

So my first question is: is this actually a problem or have I just made a stupid mistake somewhere in the use of this technique?

My second question then is: what is the most efficient and elegant way of dealing with this?

For what it's worth my current preferred method for dealing with this is to write my text files using Unix line ending style even on Windows, which is proposed in this first link as part of a strategy for C++ coding using utf-8 on Windows, and which the second link seems to hint that Microsoft themselves may be coming around to.

http://utf8everywhere.org/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/22/new-options-for-managing-character-sets-in-the-microsoft-cc-compiler/

Comment: No idea what's going on with the language syntax formatting. It's screwed up for some reason I can't fathom.

Comment: You did 3 spaces not 4

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it was so pernickety, I thought it just looked for a rational indent.

Comment: Wait, so do you want to fix those line endings and minimize wasted memory, or read the file as-is? You can't tell how many line endings are in the file before you read it. One option would be to resize after you read and know the resulting size.

Comment: You can use `gcount()` to obtain the number of characters actually read. Why not just resize the string to that size? Or, if you actually want `\r\n` preserved, open the file in binary mode.

Comment: Unix-style line endings are wrong. They are the odd ones that violate standards documents. See [Why is the line terminator CR+LF?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040318-00/?p=40193)

Comment: Read the file in binary mode and keep the \r\n

Comment: @Igor I'd forgotten about gcount and was contemplating recalculating the size of the string, that's exactly the kind of elegance I was looking for. Thanks, post it as an answer and I'll tick it.

Comment: @Sven It's bad enough having to deal with \r\n in files, you never want that line ending in your strings in memory where you'll inevitably have to compare them with other strings with plain \n line endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fileContents.resize(file.gcount())` after `read()` should do the trick.